# I have not used any database related code in my Splash page but still it is showing an error as EARLY CRASH in firebase crashlytics. This is my Crash

Tags: android, asynchronous, crash, crashlytics

> I cannot find the proper reason for this crash. I have done changes in all the dependency versions but still I am facing this issue. This is my stack trace. Mainly found in Tecno SPARK devices

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
          at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done (AsyncTask.java:399)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:383)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:252)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:271)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
          at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
          at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:170)
          at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:140)
          at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query (ContentProviderNative.java:423)
          at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:944)
          at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:880)
          at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground (CursorLoader.java:71)
          at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground (CursorLoader.java:46)
          at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground (AsyncTaskLoader.java:321)
          at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground (AsyncTaskLoader.java:74)
          at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground (AsyncTaskLoader.java:62)
          at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call (AsyncTask.java:378)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
          at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)**
```

Comment: You should the implementation causing the exception

Comment: I didn't use AsyncTask in my entire project